# Why am I getting this error code in devtools, Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket' in my console log when i am trying to run a javaScript file?

Tags: devtools

I am getting an error code in my dev tools.

Error handling response: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws/ws' is invalid.
    at init (chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:22:18)
    at chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:65:13

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: It might be a bug in one of your extensions. Open `chrome://extensions/` and deactivate extensions one by one to figure out which extension is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and like Aleksey Razbakov said, it's probably from one of your extensions. In my case I had to disabled : Live Server Web Extension. And now this error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

you should have installed a 'live server extension' in VScode previously. Go to chrome with this : chrome://extensions/
go to delete this extension package and that's it !